# Problemas con web View

Tags: java, android, android-studio

En una app de android, he utilizado un webView para que el usuario entre en un "player" que consiste en ir mostrando contenido de redes sociales de manera de presentación. No obstante, parece ser que esta página es demasiado "pesada" ya que no se carga bien del todo. ¿Hay algo que pueda hacer para que este contenido se cargue correctamente o no hay otra manera de corregir el problema que saliendo del webView y entrando en el navegador?

(Código utilizado para el WebView:)

```
   * Método para la creación de la WebView, en la que se mostrará el enlace en el que el usuario deberá introducir el ID
     */
    public void CrearWeb ()
    {
        web=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webV);

        //Habilitar JavaScript
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl(etiqueta);
    }

    /**
     * Método para abrir el player sin salir de la aplicación
     */
    public void Seguirweb ()
    {
        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
        });
        web.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
            {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    switch (keyCode) {
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                            if (web.canGoBack())
                            {
                                web.goBack();
                                return true;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
```

ACTUALIZACIÓN: Comentar que este problema va ligado a la versión de Android ya que en versiones superiores a 6.0 funciona correctamente.

Comment: Cual es el código? Agregalo por favor para no estar adivinando que tienes implementado.

Comment: ¿Que tiene que ver este problema con "android-studio"?

Answer (score 1):

Buenas,

Hay dos tipos de aceleración, la de software y la de hardware. Comentan que dependiendo del SDK que estés utilizando es mejor uno que otro, y que este código acelera el proceso:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
}       
else {
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```

Así mismo en las actividades, utilizar esto:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <activity ... />
    <activity android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />
</application>
```

La fuente es: [Enlace a fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32304237/android-webview-loading-data-performance-very-slow)

Espero haber sido de ayuda.

Comment: Que no se cargue, puede ser por otro tipo de causas, acelerar el hardware para cargar un WebView no implica que lo va a cargar.

Comment: Coincido en lo que dices, aunque podría ser que tardase demasiado y por eso no cargase, sólo di una opción. He leído tu respuesta, y puede que sea por tema del JavaScript (en servidores Microsoft pasa mucho). Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que comentas es que se carga pero no completamente:

> No obstante, parece ser que esta página es demasiado "pesada" ya que
>   no se carga bien del todo.

Lo cual puede suceder debido a que algunos elementos o funcionalidad de la página necesitan javascript, la ejecución de javascript por default no esta habilitada, así que tienes que habilitarla.

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Sin embargo es importante revises tu LogCat, puede ocurrir también que algunos recursos que cargue tu página dentro del WebView, esten siendo bloqueados por un proxy por ejemplo.

Comment: Soy nuevo en esto de android studio y no estoy familiarizado con todos los términos. ¿Podrías desarrollar más la idea del  "LogCat" indicando qué habría que hacer?

Comment: Buenas, aquí tienes la documentación de LogCat "https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html?hl=es-419" Entiendo que se refiere a que inicies el LogCat desde la consola de Android Studio y depures la aplicación y mires qué te muestra cuando está cargando la página. Saludos!!